# Calling another Controller post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, http-post

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 for my website.

I have created a partial view that has "Previous, Next and Save" buttons. I am calling this partial view on my master page.

My requirement is that on what ever `View` I am I must be able to call different `Save` methods in different controllers by passing respective `Model` data to controller actions.

**Example**

- I have 4 step data input, I have a different controller for each step.
- If i am on step 1 and i click Save the form Values should go to `Step1Controller`'s action method,
- If I am on step 2 then post should call `Step2Controller`

Something like this this:

```
public ActionResult Save(GenericModel model)
{
    //use reflection to find out model type

    //call appropriate controller action with model

    return RedirectToAction("Create", new { Controller = "Conference", Action = "Create" });
}
```

This save method will be called for `Save` button on the `Master page`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a potential mis-use of the concept of a controller and a model.  Why is a single view accessing multiple controllers for the result of a form post with the same model?  If all you need is to call other functions, by all means make a function in the same controller, but you need to re-evaluate what you are trying to do here.  Each view (or partial view) should wrap up its own form and call its own controller action upon submittal.

Answer (score 0):

Are the forms on separate actions on the controllers?

If so, just set the form action on each page to point to the relevant controller. So form 1 is

```
<form method="post" action="/step1controller/action">
```

Form 2 is:

```
<form method="post" action="/step2controller/action">
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I can not give form with controller and action name of a particular step as the same save button will be used on all other views.so its decided in a common controller that will further call the appropriate controller action. What I am trying to do is my Save button will call a controller action on each post from all the views and from there on it will be decided which save method on which controller is to be called with model passed to that action.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a private method in the controller and call in every part of the first steps.

```
private bool Save(GenericModel model)
{
   ......
}

[HttpPost]
public bool SaveStep1(GenericModel model)
{
      this.Save(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public bool SaveStep2(GenericModel model)
{
      this.Save(model);
}
```